# .net core identity change tables names

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

When i try to rename table's names i use this code below. All works good. but when i update the database, it has some old tables. for example:
`AspNetUserRoles` and new tables `UserRoles`. Why is this happening? thanks

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    // Customizations
    builder.Entity<User>(i =>
    {
        i.ToTable("Users");
        i.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    });
    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>(i =>
    {
        i.ToTable("Roles");
        i.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    });
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<Guid>>(i =>
    {
        i.ToTable("UserRoles");
        i.HasKey(x => new { x.RoleId, x.UserId });
    });
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<Guid>>(i =>
    {
        i.ToTable("UserLogins");
        i.HasKey(x => new { x.ProviderKey, x.LoginProvider });
    });
    builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>>(i =>
    {
        i.ToTable("RoleClaims");
        i.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    });
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<Guid>>(i =>
    {
        i.ToTable("UserClaims");
        i.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    });
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<Guid>>(i =>
    {
        i.ToTable("UserTokens");
        i.HasKey(x => x.UserId);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I do it and it works fine with migrations/update.

```
base.OnModelCreating(builder);

builder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("UserRoles");
builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("UserClaims");
builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("UserLogins");
builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("RoleClaims");
builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToTable("UserTokens");
```

Also note that I don't use the `Guid` type. Microsoft uses `string` for their Id columns so we'll use that too.